# Hololens Shared environment custommessage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, callback, server, hololens

I'm working on shared environment, and I have succeeded in sending message from user a to b. now I'm trying to send vectors that change the position of a gameobject, for instance person a moves a cube, person b sees the movement. This is currently not working for me. The message is send but is not received. I tested this heavily. I use the microsoft Hololens academy shared environment library.

I will post a code sample that works. And after that a code sample that is currently not working. Working code:

First I subscribe the callback method to the messageID with:

```
protected override void Start()
{
    base.Start();
    CustomMessages.Instance.MessageHandlers[CustomMessages.TestMessageID.StartMachine] = this.startMachine;
}
```

The subscribed method:

```
private void startMachine(NetworkInMessage msg)
{
// do something
    Act();
}
```

this method is called when a button is pressed, which in turn broadcasts this information by calling a method on a static class.

```
protected override void PerformManipulationStart(Vector3 position)
{
    //broadcasting message
    CustomMessages.Instance.SendStartMachine();
    //the below statement is some local action
    MachineMovement.Instance.StartMachine();
}
```

The method that broadcasts

```
public void SendStartMachine()
{
    // If we are connected to a session, broadcast our head info
    if (this.serverConnection != null && this.serverConnection.IsConnected())
    {
        // Create an outgoing network message to contain all the info we want to send
        NetworkOutMessage msg = CreateMessage((byte)TestMessageID.StartMachine);

        // Send the message as a broadcast, which will cause the server to forward it to all other users in the session.
        this.serverConnection.Broadcast(
            msg,
            MessagePriority.Immediate,
            MessageReliability.Reliable,
            MessageChannel.Avatar);
    }
}
```

I found an error before in the testmessage enum. If you put something below max then the message will not be broadcasted. I placed the UpdateMachinePosition on several locations but it's still not called. All other testmessage ID's work.

```
public enum TestMessageID : byte
{
    HeadTransform = MessageID.UserMessageIDStart,
    UserAvatar,
    UserHit,
    ShootProjectile,
    StageTransform,
    ResetStage,
    ExplodeTarget,
    StartMachine,
    UpdateMachinePosition,
    StopMachine,
    Alarm,
    Mash,
    Max
}
```

So  here is the code of the class where the broadcast is sent but not received. If one moves an gameobject. The change is not received on the other Hololenses.

Subscribing the method to the messageID:

```
protected override void Start() {
    base.Start();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    //subscribed in the line below.  
  CustomMessages.Instance.MessageHandlers[CustomMessages.TestMessageID.UpdateMachinePosition] = this.RemoteMachinePosition;
}
```

The subscibed method, currently just using destroy to test if something happens, destroy has been seperately tested and works:

```
void RemoteMachinePosition(NetworkInMessage msg)
{
    Destroy(totransform.gameObject);

}
```

The method doing something when called locally. Again I have tested several times that the message is being send:

```
public override void performAction()
{
        // 4.a: Calculate the moveVector as position - manipulationPreviousPosition.
        moveVector = (ManipulationManager.Instance.ManipulationPosition - manipulationPreviousPosition) *2;

        // 4.a: Update the manipulationPreviousPosition with the current position.
        manipulationPreviousPosition = ManipulationManager.Instance.ManipulationPosition;

        // 4.a: Increment this transform's position by the moveVector.
        totransform.position += moveVector;
        // calling custommessage class to broadcast.
        CustomMessages.Instance.SendMachineTransform(moveVector, name);
}
```

The method called on the custommessage class:

```
public void SendMachineTransform(Vector3 Movement, string Name)
{
    // If we are connected to a session, broadcast our head info
    if (this.serverConnection != null && this.serverConnection.IsConnected())
    {
        // Create an outgoing network message to contain all the info we want to send
        NetworkOutMessage msg = CreateMessage((byte)TestMessageID.UpdateMachinePosition);


        // Send the message as a broadcast, which will cause the server to forward it to all other users in the session.
        this.serverConnection.Broadcast(
            msg,
            MessagePriority.Immediate,
            MessageReliability.Reliable,
            MessageChannel.Avatar);
    }
}
```

All suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

We struggled with same problem and finally found a solution.

Add:

```
msg.ReadInt64();
```

To the method that is receiving messages so the whole things looks like that:

```
void RemoteMachinePosition(NetworkInMessage msg)
{
    msg.ReadInt64();
    Destroy(totransform.gameObject);
}
```

The message is sent in bytes. The thing you are reading first is user ID and not the message itself. After adding the readint line it should skip the User ID and receive rest of the message.